# how to draw line chart with date fomat on excel using openpyxl of python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I draw a line chart on excel using openpyxl

In excel sheet:

```
     date     value
"2015-05-01" | 0.1
"2015-05-02" | 0.2
"2015-05-03" | 0.3
"2015-05-04" | 0.4
```

But it gives integer format for date data like "45612"... How could I draw line chart with date format? (date is x-axis, and value is y-axis)

Comment: Custom format is this : "yyyy-mm-dd"

Comment: I prefer 2007 Version but I have other versions also(2010, 2013). So version is not much matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this: `chart.x_axis.number_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd'`